# Vue + Spring: Does not pass the CORS test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, vue.js, spring-security, cors

My Spring application is running on the address localhost:8081
My frontend Vue.js is running on the address localhost:8080.

I have the WebMvcConfig:

```
...

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addMapping("*")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
    }

}
```

I have the request in Vue component

```
import HTTP from '../api/http-common'
...
 HTTP.post('/registration', this.form)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.data.errors) {
                            this.errors = response.data.errors
                        } else {
                            this.$router.push("/");
                        }
                    })
```

Here http-common

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8081/api'
})
```

It used to work, I had in WebMvcConfig next:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addMapping("/api/registration")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
    }

}
```

Then I had to make a request to the address localhost:8081/api/activate/{code}.
And I replace "/api/registration" on "/api/activate/**" But it doesn't work. Now both settings don't work.

I want to allow all request from localhost:8080(where my frontend Vue.js is runnning)

I have next CORS test in browser Chrome:

```
GENERAL
Request URL: http://localhost:8081/api/registration
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: [::1]:8081
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADER
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 20
Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2019 09:30:42 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

REQUEST HEADER
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/registration
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
```

Error from console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/api/registration' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

createError.js?2d83:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:81)
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to write next, then it's work:

```
.addMapping("/api/**")
```